# Как написать итератор простых чисел

Tags: python, простые-числа

```
class LowerPrime:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def __iter__(self):
        self.it = 0
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.it == 2:
            raise StopIteration
        num = []
        for n in range(self.number):
            for i in range(2, n):
                if n % i == 0:
                    break
            else:
                num.append(n)
        print(num)

lower_prime = LowerPrime(number=11)
lower_prime_it = iter(lower_prime)
next(lower_prime_it)
```

Задача состоит в следующем. На входе есть например число 11. При каждом вызове next выводится меньшее простое число 7 следующий next выводит 5 и так далее. Как только достигли 2 выводим ошибку  Stopiteration. Обязательное условие задачи использовать написанный в ручную итератор и вызов должен выглядеть так как в примере. В моем понимаеии нужно создать список простых чисел по убыванию и при каждом вызове через next выводить по одному числу.
Вот так :

```
next(lower_prime_it) == 7
next(lower_prime_it) == 5
```

Получилось создать список с простыми числами но не получается вывести их по очередно через next. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться что не так

Comment: Написал код но он не работает как хотелось. Помогите разобраться пожалуйста что с ним не так

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так то и ваш код можно переделать под работающий с минимальными изменениями:

```py
class LowerPrime:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def __iter__(self):
        self.it = self.number
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.it < 2:
            raise StopIteration
        num = []
        for n in range(self.it, 1, -1):
            for i in range(2, n):
                if n % i == 0:
                    break
            else:
                self.it = n - 1
                return n

lower_prime = LowerPrime(number=11)
for i in lower_prime:
    print(i)
for i in lower_prime:
    print(i)
```

Вывод:

```
11
7
5
3
2
11
7
5
3
2
```

Но в некоторых случаях мой код будет работать недостаточно правильно, например, если нужно параллельно итерироваться по двум итераторам от одного объекта `LowerPrime`:

```py
print(list(zip(lower_prime, lower_prime)))
# [(11,), (7,), (5,), (3,), (2,)]
```

В этом случае подойдёт [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1440803/260769) Stanislav Volodarskiy с отдельным объектом-итератором.

Comment: Обычный способ пропустить первый элемент и обработать остальные: `next(lower_prime); for p in lower_prime: pass`. Не работает - `for` вызывает `iter(lower_prime)`, а этот вызов переустанавливает итератор на начало. Поэтому важно чтобы `__iter__`  не менял состояние итератора.

Comment: Есть `iterable`. Каждый вызов `iter(iterable)` порождает новый итератор, все итераторы независимы. Состояние `iterable` неизменно. Есть `iterator`. Каждый вызов `iter(iterator)` возвращает сам `iterator`. Состояние `iterator` неизменно.

Answer (score 1):

У задачи есть две стороны: математическая и технологическая. Математическую я предельно упростил - простота числа проверяется по определению. Можно сделать быстрее, но пока так.

Технологическая сторона. Я сделаю `LowerPrime` аналогом [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range). В Питоне `range` - неизменяемая последовательность. Из последовательности можно получить сколько угодно итераторов. Все итераторы полностью независимы. Демонстрация:

> ```
> @>>> r = range(10)
> @>>> r
> range(0, 10)
> @>>> it = iter(r)
> @>>> it
> <range_iterator object at 0x7fc241c2b630>
> @>>> it2 = iter(r)
> @>>> it2
> <range_iterator object at 0x7fc241c2a7f0>
> ```

Схема "одна последовательность - много итераторов" нужна чтобы работал код вроде:

```
r = range(10)
for n in r:     # for вызывает iter(r) в начале
    # что-то делаем
for n in r:     # for вызывает iter(r) в начале
    # что-то делаем
```

Без разных итераторов второй цикл не выполнится, так как первый исчерпал свой итератор полностью и нам нужен новый итератор.

Тоже самое для списка. Список один, итераторов много:

> ```
> @>>> lst = [1, 2, 3]
> @>>> it = iter(lst)
> @>>> it
> <list_iterator object at 0x7fc241d12710>
> @>>> it2 = iter(lst)
> @>>> it2
> <list_iterator object at 0x7fc241c781c0>
> ```

Становится ясно, что нужны два класса. Для списка убывающих простых `LowerPrime`, для итераторов `LowerPrimeIter`. Список простых заранее можно не составлять. Каждый вызов `next` продолжает поиск простых с того места, где итератор остановился раньше:

```
def is_prime(n):
    return all(n % i != 0 for i in range(2, n))


class LowerPrime:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self._number = number

    def __iter__(self):
        return LowerPrimeIter(self._number)


class LowerPrimeIter:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self._n = n + 1

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self._n <= 2:
            raise StopIteration
        while True:
            self._n -= 1
            if is_prime(self._n):
                return self._n


lower_prime = LowerPrime(number=11)
lower_prime_it = iter(lower_prime)
print('first', next(lower_prime_it))
for p in lower_prime_it:
    print(p)
```

> ```
> $ python lower_prime.py
> first 11
> 7
> 5
> 3
> 2
> ```

Comment: Мне кажется, отдельный объект для итераций нужен только в совсем уж экзотическом случае, когда нужна параллельная итерация по двум `iter` от одного объекта `LowerPrime`. Например, `print(list(zip(lower_prime, lower_prime)))` у вас отработает правильно, а с кодом из моего ответа нет. А просто для отдельных итераций `for` отдельный объект-итератор не нужен.